# My S7 wont sync my gmail email app

Tags: sync, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s7

So for some reason I cant sync my gmail emails to the new S7 I purchased. I've verified its in "no power saving mode", sync is enabled for the app, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and deleting and deleting the accounts and putting them back on. Im not sure this is relevant but it was working for 2 hrs or so and isnt now. Nothing works please help!